# Visual Studio Android Emulator does not show the app content

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

i don't know why, when i run the application, it shows nothing. I put a simple button and, the emulator only shows like the "project" name nothing else.
[This is the preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U7Xl.png)

[And this is when the project is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYunY.png)

pretty sure it's not a speed problem, i have a good computer.

**Main.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button1" />
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace App1
{
    [Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            // SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            Button btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it would help immensely if you showed us your code.

Comment: right. I didnt put the code because it's the simplest code  but, here it is:
https://puu.sh/wuc8P/ac88e68a3d.png
https://puu.sh/wuc5H/f1fb5f2446.png

Comment: do NOT post code as images

Comment: Hello! As @Jason said, please make sure to post your code *in* your question. If you copy and paste it in the question, you can even format it to look like code, which is very helpful for other people trying to help you.

Comment: yeah sorry, im very new at this forum

Comment: Did you try removing the app from your emulator, cleaning and re-building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to uncomment this line:

```
 // SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
```

Basically by commenting it you have killed the only connection between your axml file and your backend code.

Comment: @NEURO as you said that you are new, some more things - saying thanks should be avoided, though it is possible if you really think it is necessary. But you should upvote the useful answers and mark the right answer by clicking the checker below it always.